# Getting error "Action Error: Missing result from request body"

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm running one of the examples in my own project and running into the error.

**Action Error: Missing result from request body**

Github Sample Project: [dialogflow-silly-name-maker-webhook-nodejs](https://github.com/actions-on-google/apiai-silly-name-maker-webhook-nodejs)

**Hookbin:**  Shows the webhook coming from the assistant.https://hookbin.com/bin/ZjPzJ1Yb

Might there be an error in the sample code or in my set-up?

Comment: Can you provide a more complete error message or error stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error. In my case it was because the request object I was passing to ActionsSdkApp() constructor had a body property which was a JSON string as opposed to data structure.

Adding this in before instantiating ActionsSdkApp fixed it for me...

```
request.body = JSON.parse(request.body);
```

Then I could carry on like this...

```
App = new ActionsSdkApp({'request': request, 'response': response});
```

Comment: Thanks man! That fixed my problem after hours of struggling! 
I'm using version 1.7.0 and I remark that even using the map **actionMap.set(app.StandardIntents.MAIN, mainIntent);** doesn't work. I had to put the value directly **actionMap.set('actions.intent.MAIN', mainIntent);**

Answer (score 0):

That error message is printed by the Action on Google client library if the incoming request doesn't have the intent information, but your JSON looks good.

Make sure your action enables debug logging for the client library: `process.env.DEBUG = 'actions-on-google:*';`

Then study the complete log to understand your issue.